# Javascript - Base class method not available in derived class when extending using lodAsh

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, lodash

I have a base class :

```
class Base {
    constructor() { 
        this.name = "base_class"    
    }

    getBaseName() {
    return "base"
    }

}
```

and a Derived class

```
var _ = require('lodash');
class Derived {
    constructor() {
        this.name = "derived"
    }

    getDerivedName() {
        return "derived"
    }
}
_.extend(Derived.prototype, Base)
```

I was expecting to have `getBaseName` available in the derived class. But its not the case. What should I do for that? What am I missing?

```
var derived = new Derived();
console.log(derived.getBaseName)
-- undefined
```

Comment: Shouldn't it be `_.extend(Derived.prototype, Base.prototype)`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why are you using lodash to extend ES6 classes? Can't you just use the `extends` keyword?

```
class Derived extends Base {
    constructor() {
        super();
        this.name = "derived"
    }
    getDerivedName() {
        return this.name;
    }
}
```

Comment: I dont know the actual answer but it was told that using extends with babel has some issue with IE and so we are not allowed to use extends.

Comment: I suggest you look into traceur compiler then, https://github.com/google/traceur-compiler; doesn't make much sense to use babel for classes if it's breaking on this very basic use-case.

Comment: ok I will look at it.Here's the caveat about extends -- https://babeljs.io/docs/usage/caveats/